# Как передать this дальше?

Tags: javascript, функции, this, return

У меня есть функция:

```
function CrFunc(){
  // this1
  return function(){
    //this2
    this.x++;
  }
}
```

Она вызывается так :

```
var Nfunc = CrFunc.call(SomeObj); 
Nfunc();
```

Как сделать this2  = this1? Т.е. Чтобы возвращалась функция с this'ом объекта. 
Кроме как

```
Nfunc.call(SomeObj);//apply
```

это нельзя больше никак реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function CrFunc(){
  // this1
  return (function(){
    //this2
    this.x++;
  }).bind(this); // this is this1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно также использовать [стрелочные функции](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru-RU/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

```js
function CrFunc() {
  this.x = 0;
  return () => this.x++;
}

const d = CrFunc();

console.log(d());
console.log(d());
```